# Error while installing VSFTPD in passive mode - 500 OOPS: could not bind listening IPv4 socket

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp, vsftpd, ftps

I am trying to install and connect to FTPS server (passive mode) locally. I have read similar topics in this community, but still can't fix the problem or find an error in the `vsftpd.conf`. Firewall is disabled, socket `192,168.1.90:21` answers to ping (can connect via telnet). Could you help me solve this?

Here's my configuration (uncommented lines):

```
listen=YES
listen_address=192.168.1.90
listen_port=21
listen_ipv6=NO

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
setproctitle_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
syslog_enable=NO
log_ftp_protocol=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

connect_from_port_20=NO

chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=NO
force_local_data_ssl=NO
force_local_logins_ssl=NO
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.users
userlist_deny=NO

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=20021
pasv_max_port=20024
```

Output of `lsof -i:21`:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
vsftpd  15054 root    3u  IPv4 228839      0t0  TCP ex-srv:ftp (LISTEN)
```

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to bind an already binded (in use) port, in this case 21/TCP.